# Почему файл вроде создается, но не находится?

Tags: java, android

Создаю файл:

```
File FileOut = new File(aMain.getContext().getFilesDir() + "/" + filePath, "ses1");
try { 
    log.i(TAG, "FileOut: " + FileOut.getCanonicalPath()); 
} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Выводится правильный путь к файлу. Но когда пытаюсь проверить вот так:

```
if (FileOut.exists()) log.i(TAG, "Yes"); else log.i(TAG, "No");
```

Выводит "No"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызов `new File` создает не сам файл, а класс для работы с файлом, который *может быть* расположен по указанному пути
`exists` - проверяет существует ли файл *физически* на диске
Чтобы он появился, нужно записать в него данные, с помощью потока вывода, например `FileOutputStream(file)`, больше про потоки ввода/вывода можно посмотреть в [оф.документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html)

Чтобы создать пустой файл, можно использовать `Files.createFile()`, но данный метод доступен только с 26 API

Comment: Если я использую эту же проверку при связывании класса FileOut с sd картой, то все нормально. Если же я пытаюсь связать класс FileOut с диском устройства, то на моменте OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(FileOut); программа падает. Т.е. на SD файл создается, а на устройстве нет.

Comment: `при связывании класса FileOut с sd картой`
Файлом на карте? Или папкой на карте? Можете дополнить вопрос, приведя используемый код?

Comment: @kaaa, все папки на пути к файлу должны существовать на момент создания файла. Подозреваю, что Вы их не создаёте.

Comment: Да, оказалось, что при записи на диск устройства нужная папка не создавалась, а при записи на SD карту создавалась автоматически.

Answer (score 0):

Файл только в памяти, пока он не закрывается. Закройте его перед тестом

```
if (FileOut.exists())
```